# How to update a new pose in iterative pose optimization problem?

Tags: slam, computer-vision

There are multiple ways to update new pose in iterative pose optimization problem. The easiest one we often find in papers in robotics is as

SO3 + translation

Update on right
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf {R}' &= \textbf{R} \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}, \textbf {t}' = \textbf{t} + \delta\textbf{t}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Update on left
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf {R}' &= \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}\textbf{R} , \textbf {t}' = \textbf{t} + \delta\textbf{t}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\delta\textbf{t}\in R^3, \boldsymbol{\omega}\in R^3$ are estimated update on the pose with $\textbf{R}\in SO(3),\textbf{t}\in R^2$.

But there are other ways as well, such as

SE3 Matrix update

Right side update $\textbf {T}'=\delta\textbf{T}\textbf{T}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf {T}' &=\delta\textbf{T} \textbf{T}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}&\delta\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{R}&\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1  
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}\textbf{R}&\textbf{} \delta\textbf{t}+\textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\label{eq:disp} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf {T}' &=   \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\xi}]_\times} \textbf{T}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}&\textbf{V} \delta\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{R}&\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1  
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}\textbf{R}&\textbf{V} \delta\textbf{t}+\textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Left side update $\textbf {T}'=\textbf{T}\delta\textbf{T}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf {T}' &=  \textbf{T}\delta \textbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{R}&\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}&\delta\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{R}\textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}&\textbf{R}\delta\textbf{t}+\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf {T}' &=  \textbf{T}\textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\xi}]
_\times}=\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{R}&\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}&\textbf{V} \delta\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{R}\textbf{e}^{[\boldsymbol{\omega}]
_\times}&\textbf{R}\textbf{V} \delta\textbf{t}+\textbf{t} \\ 
\textbf{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

se3 6x1 pose update($\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{I}}^{-1}$ could be left or right jacobian)

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\xi}'=\boldsymbol{\xi} + \boldsymbol{\mathfrak{I}}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\xi}
\end{equation}

My question is that which one is most stable or prefered.
If you know any reference toward this problem, please let me know.

Thanks!